# SSIS Execute Process Task inside Foreach Loop container: selectively unzip files having value of dateFilter variable

Tags: ssis

Please advise on how to get Foreach Loop Contaiiner coordinated with the Execute Process Task so that only 2014-06-20 files are unzipped when my package user variable user::datePart = 2014-06-20.

source folder has 4 zip files with 2 different time stamps (sample):

> ```
>     2014-06-20_24632_1403294308_settings_publisher.txt.zip
>     2014-06-20_24632_1403294309_settings_campaign.txt.zip
>     2014-06-21_24632_1403294308_settings_publisher.txt
>     2014-06-21_24632_1403294309_settings_campaign.txt
> ```

What I've tried:

package variable user::datePart set to 2014-06-20

foreach loop container:

- collection Foreach File Enumerater expressions: FileSpec =@[User::datePart] +"*.txt.zip"
- collection Folder: C:\Users\me\Downloads\MarinmultipleZipped Files: *.txt.zip
- collection Files: *.txt.zip
- collection Retrieve file name: Fully qualified
- variable mappings I set User::zippedFile set to 0

inside foreach loop container an Execute Process Task

- Task property DelayValidation = True
- Process executable = C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe,
- expressions property Arguments = "e " +@[User::zippedFile]+ " " +"-C:\Users\me\Downloads\test2"

when I run this, it looks like success, but only the first two files are unzipping, and this is regardless of whether timestamp is 2014-06-20 or  2014-06-21 - which is very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing the '.txt' part like this:

```
 collection Foreach File Enumerater expressions: FileSpec =@[User::datePart] +"*.zip"
```

Comment: Thank you. the root of the problem was the filetype suffix used.  I changed and it's now working. I didn't realize/see how the filetype endings were different for the different zipped files.  Uggh...so much time it took.  Thanks!!